# cutting and extending one polygon layer in function to the other layer boundaries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, vector, editing, data-management

I'd like a methodology that can edit my vector layer, extending and cutting the features in the polygon layer "cap_agricola" within the boundary layer "sp_edr", I would like to solve this problem in ArcGIS, but I can do without restrictions in GRASS or QGIS.

[image: Problem - Cut and Extending cap_agricola layer to the sp_edr boudaries layer]

Answer (score 2):

Just use the **[Erase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000m000000)** function in ArcGIS for Desktop (if you have an **Advanced** license which allows it).

Answer (score 1):

There are two tools within [ET GeoWizard for ArcGIS](http://www.ian-ko.com/) that will give you the result that you are looking for.

1. [Erase](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/ToolBox/toolbox_Erase.htm)
2. [Polygon Global Snap](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/Snap_Polygon_Wizard.htm)